# Phonegap - Android FileSystem requesting error: LocalFileSystem is not defined

Tags: android, cordova

I use phonegap for a project where i want to get info from a file. It works fine on iOS devices, but it fails to work on Android and i don't know the reason. Here's my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 

    try {             
        alert('start');
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
});
```

This always fail and the catch prints the following error:

> ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined

I'm using phonegap 2.0.0. I also have the required fields in config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

EDIT

```
MainActivity.java:
package com.example.scoreboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent; 


public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.init();
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue",60000);
    /*    super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false); */
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.scoreboard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission." />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: this answer might help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989656/phonegap-unable-to-write-to-file-for-android

Comment: in that case file writing's not working because 'deviceReady' wasn't firing at all. That is why you have to change deviceReady to $(document).ready(function () { /*...*/ }); but as you can see i already did that.

Comment: can u post whole activity class and manifest code in here?

Comment: well everything seems ok. I managed to reproduce the error and went through the examples in official PhoneGap docs. Their example throws same error with window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
I aplologize but i cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: it's okay, thank you for trying. my solution was to store the info i needed as a single record in a datatable. It's ugly, but at least working. So i would be glad, if another solution would come up :D

Comment: well you can try to insert it into database instead of FileSystem
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
(this example works, I've tried it :))